# Firebase on value change update list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to learn React Native by building my own little app. I have the possibility of adding and editing items that are added to a home screen. The problem is that the list is not updated automatically, but has to be refreshed by the user. This leads to that they might not notice the changes they did, or that they wonder where the new item is.

This is the code i currently have for the home screen. It retrieves all the objects of a user and adds them to a flatlist.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.loadFeed(this.state.userId);
}

addToFlatList = (food_feed, data, food) => {
  const that = this;
  const foodObj = data[food];

  database.ref('users').child(this.state.userId).child('username').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    if (exists) {
      food_feed.push({
        id: food,
        amount: foodObj.amount,
        bestBefore: foodObj.bestBeforeDate,
        description: foodObj.description,
        name: foodObj.name,
        useBy: foodObj.useByDate
      });

      that.setState({
        refresh: false
      });
    }
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

loadFeed = (userId) => {
  this.setState({
    refresh: true,
    food_feed: []
  });

  const that = this;
  const loadRef = database.ref('users').child(userId).child('foods');

  loadRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    if (exists) {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      const food_feed = that.state.food_feed;

      that.setState({
        empty: false
      });

      for (const food in data) {
        that.addToFlatList(food_feed, data, food);
      }
    } else {
      that.setState({
        empty: true,
        refresh: false
      });
    }
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

I've done a few searches, but can't seem to get the result that I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `on()` instead of `once()`. With `once()` the data is gotten from Firebase once (hence the name), and then passed to your code. When you use `on()` it does the same, but then keeps listening for changes to the data, and will call your code again whenever the data changes.

With `on()` your feed listener would look like this:

```
loadFeed = (userId) => {
  this.setState({
    refresh: true,
    food_feed: []
  });

  const loadRef = database.ref('users').child(userId).child('foods');

  loadRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      const food_feed = this.state.food_feed;

      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        let foodObj = child.val();
        food_feed.push({
          id: child.key,
          amount: foodObj.amount,
          bestBefore: foodObj.bestBeforeDate,
          description: foodObj.description,
          name: foodObj.name,
          useBy: foodObj.useByDate
        });
      }

      this.setState({
        empty: false,
        food_feed: food_feed
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        empty: true,
        refresh: false
      });
    }
  }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
})
```

As you'll note, I've also simplified the code since you weren't using the user name anyway. I also changed it to use fat arrow functions everywhere, so that you don't need a `that` anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to get the function to run correctly, but I now know about the .on function for firebase.